# Necesito que un boton siempre este en el mismo lugar respecto a una imagen de fondo en HTML

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Tengo un imagen "x" que coloque en un "div" que abarca todo el tamaño de la pantalla en todas las resoluciones. La cuestion es que le tengo que colocar botones encima y necesito que esten en un lugar determinado. Ej:

La imagen tiene un cuadro "Menu" al cual le tengo que colocar el boton encima. Le coloco el boton en una resolucion de 1024x768 pero al pasar a una resolucion mas pequeña o mas grande, el boton me aparece en otra parte de la imagen.

¿Como puedo hacer?

Comment: Coloca tu codigo para poder ayudarte

Comment: Usa `control + M` para abrir la función de fragmento de código y ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Colocar snippets (fragmentos de còdigo) es impresindible para poder ayudar, sin embargo con lo que pude captar de tu issue, mi sugerencia serìa:

Al div que ocupa el 100x100 agrega `position: relative` dentro de este div agrega un segundo div, dentro de ese nuevo div agrega el botòn que quieres y ademàs, a ese div agrega las propiedades `position: absolute; bottom: 10%; left 10%; display: inline-block;` "juega" con los porcentajes para acomodar a tu gusto.